# how to find the table name and column name from a error message sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are converting `triggers`  in our `application tables` with `foreign keys` for performance optimization. The `triggers` are having custom error messages in case of `referential integrity violation`. After changing triggers to foreign keys, we are using error handling to capture error messages. for instance the error message thrown after a `foreign key violation`

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_test". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.test",
>   column 'Code'.

we need to extract the `table name` and `column name` from this error message dynamically to put them in the `custom error message`. Is there any way we can get the `table name` and `column name` from the error message. We can use some string operations like `charindex` but i am looking other options

Comment: I don't see any other options here besides string manipulation.

Comment: SQL is not a good tool for string parsing and analysis. You may consider passing this off to a string parsing/extraction routine writting in a proper programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** You can retrieve the table and column name using `CHARINDEX` as condition of `sys` tables as below:

It's a dynamic solution though `CHARINDEX` is used and nothing is hardcoded here so I hope it will be useful for you.

```
DECLARE @document VARCHAR(5000)
SET @document = '
        The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_test". 
        The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.test", column ''Code''.'

SELECT t.name AS table_name, 
    c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE CHARINDEX(t.[name], @document) > 0  
    AND CHARINDEX(c.[name], @document) > 0
```

Make the search more robust by adding `dbo` as prefix as below:

```
CHARINDEX(CONCAT('dbo.',t.[name]), @document) > 0 --For SQLSERVER2012 or +
CHARINDEX('dbo.'+ t.[name], @document) > 0 --For All Version
```

Comment: thanks. but it gives table name as state. i think we have table named state in the database

Comment: whatever term that matches with table name in @document will be returned

Comment: Apply the search with `dbo.` prefix as I have updated above it will give you the exact table and column name.